# expdp Hangs at DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/POST_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, datapump, expdp

Expdp Hangs at Below Stage for long time even in structure backup also .

```
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PRE_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/PROCOBJ
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SYSTEM_PROCOBJACT/POST_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM
```

Database Version: -**Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production**

so please let me know to get solution & if it is 12c Bug then please mention bug number also

P.S :-
here is expdp full script

```
 expdp username/password full=Y CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY directory=DIR1 dumpfile=structure_backup.dmp logfile=structure_backup.log KEEP_MASTER=Y
```

**Database Size :- 10 GB**

Comment: Thanks for participating on DBA.SE. Please consider reading the following article: _[How do I ask a good question?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (Help Centre)_. Currently your question doesn't contain enough information and might be closed as [**unclear what you're asking**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). For example, could you add the `.par` file you are using for the export or the exact command? It might be relevant for the answer which objects and/or schemas you are exporting or excluding from export. How large is your database?

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional information. Do you receive an error message in the `alert_<SID>.log` (or the alert log according to your Oracle SID installation)? Is there any information in the `structure_backup.log` file?

Comment: No, i can not find anything in both alert file & structure_backup.log file & structure backup completes it backup  but it take 2 hours  which is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end it's just a time issue you have. You would have to open up a ticket with Oracle if you want to speed things up. This is probably not an Oracle issue, but possibly an issue with your database design.

You have to understand that the Data Pump Export Utility has to determine all relevant constraints and relations before it can create a valid structured metadata export. This can take a substantial amount of time and depends on the structure of your database, the amount of schemas and other limiting constraints.

The more complex the metadata is, the longer it can take to export.

You might want to look at the object after the `.../POST_SYSTEM_ACTIONS/PROCACT_SYSTEM` as that could actually be the limiting factor.

You might want to have a look at the official documentation regarding [Database Utilities | Data Pump Performance | Tuning Performance](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-68EE06E4-FB26-4B56-86A9-1A93ACBE1454.htm#SUTIL969) (Oracle 12c Documentation) for additional ideas on how to speed up things.

Comment: ok i will open the ticket. but the thing is it takes a time after 12c up -gradation .by the way thanks for help

Comment: Yes, we have noticed performance differences between `exp` and `expdp` too after migrating from 11g to 12c. It doesn't mean that `expdp` is less performant, just different.